# Generate an array of random values from a created function to be plotted

Tags: python, random, numpy

I have a function:

```
f = x**0.5*numpy.exp(-x/150)
```

I used numpy and matplot.lib to generate a plot of f as a function of x with x:

```
x = np.linspace(0.0,1000.0, num=10.0)
```

I am wondering how do I create an array of random x values would create the same plot for this function using the x array I first made?

Bryan

Comment: I'm confused as what you really want...what do you mean by "using the x array i first made?"

Comment: Sorry, I meant finding values for another array (z) such that when I plot z vs x it will look like f vs x.

Comment: well then it wouldn't be a random array, it would have to be specially selected. And theoretically it couldn't be identical because then f would have to equal z...why do you want to do this anyways?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not quite clear what you're asking, but is it as simple as just wanting non-regularly-spaced points in your "x" array?

If so consider doing a cumulative summation on an array of random values.

As a quick example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xmin, xmax, num = 0, 1000, 20
func = lambda x: np.sqrt(x) * np.exp(-x / 150)

# Generate evenly spaced data...
x_even = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, num)

# Generate randomly spaced data...
x = np.random.random(num).cumsum()
# Rescale to desired range
x = (x - x.min()) / x.ptp()
x = (xmax - xmin) * x + xmin

# Plot the results
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True)
for x, ax in zip([x_even, x_rand], axes):
    ax.plot(x, func(x), marker='o', mfc='red')
axes[0].set_title('Evenly Spaced Points')
axes[1].set_title('Randomly Spaced Points')
plt.show()
```

[image]